# tree (bst,maxHeap) in java

Tags: java, c#, data-structures, tree, binary-tree

This information is related to what type of tree. In other words, you should recognize that this information The peak of the pyramid(Max Heap), or binary search tree or a combination of both or none of them do not.
Input format is as follows:
    (94,RR) (17,L) (36,RL) (51,R) (20,) (76,RRR) ()
Input format each node in the tree for a given pair. The first value represents the amount of Node and the second value represents the root path that must be navigated to get to this node. Node Has no way represents the root of the tree. With this information you should be able to type Identify the tree.
For example, the tree is as follows:

```
(94,RR) (17,L) (36,RL) (51,R) (20,) (76,RRR) ()
```

[tree for this string](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Ehsu.jpg)

this tree is not a maximum pyramid(max Heap),not a binary search tree and not a combination of there.

```
Entrance :
At the entrance you get a string that information is relevant to a tree. Each tree
With the statement (s) end. Entry Exit program ends.
Output:
You are one of the following phrases in your printed output.

1.BST: If the input tree is a binary search tree.
2.MaxHeap: If the tree is the maximum pyramid entrance.  
3.BST MaxHeap: If the combined input of binary search tree and the pyramid is the maximum.
4.Nothing: If there is none of the above.

**Sample Input:**
(94,RR) (17,L) (36,RL) (51,R) (20,) (76,RRR) ()
(94,) (59,LL) (61,RR) (53,LR) (79,L) (77,R) (15,RL) ()
(72,) (44,LR) (15,L) (2,LL) ()
Exit
**Sample Output:**
Nothing
MaxHeap
BST
```

Now I cant implementation tree for this question.please help.
 Thank you.

Comment: And what your question? I cann't found question, just task. If It's homework, nobody in SO doing your homework for you, sorry.

Comment: Why nobody? I don't mind doing it. Let's $150/ hour. Deal, @moha6421?

Comment: Ok, nobody for free :)

Comment: forgive me i cant implementation tree for this question.please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us represent your data in an array. We can construct a binary tree from that array by using the formula `2*i` for the left child of node `i` and `2*i+1` for the right child of node `i`. I am also assuming you have your own basic BST ready.

**1. How to determine if the given tree is a BST:** Sort the input by the size of the `String` representing the positions of the tree. Your data can be stored in a class called `Pair` which stores an integer representing the value and a string representing the position relative to the root. We can then sort it. Here's how you can implement the class and the array which stores it:

```
class Pair
{
    int val;
    String pos;
    Pair(int val, String pos)
    {
        this.val=val;
        this.pos=pos;
    }
}
```

Now in the main method or wherever, you can start building your tree array

```
int n;
//Take n which is number of nodes here
Pair[] input=new Pair[n];
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    input[i]=new Pair(*input value*, *input Position*);
}

Arrays.sort(input, new Comparator<Book>() //Sorts by the distance from start node
{
    @Override
    public int compare(Pair p1, Pair p2)
    {
        return p1.pos.length()-p2.pos.length();
    }
});
```

Now, simply create a recursive method in your BST called `Insert(Node curr, int value, String where, int tillWhere)'. I am assuming again, that your BST has a`Node` class which stores the data, as well as left and right child references.

```
class Node //The node for the BSt should look something like this 
{
    Node left, right;
    int data;
    Node(Node left, Node right, int data)
    {
        this.left=left;
        this.right=right;
        this.data=data;
    }
}

<br>

//Method for inserting into the BST
void Insert(Node curr, int value, String where, int tillWhere)
{
    if(curr==null)
        curr=new Node(value);
    else
    {
        if(where.charAt(tillWhere)=='L')
            Insert(curr.left, value, where, tillWhere+1);
        else
            Insert(curr.right, value, where, tillWhere+1);
    }
}
```

Now, simply perform an `In-order traversal` of the BST and store the results in the array `Inorder`. After that if the data is in sorted order, It will be a BST.

```
ArrayList<Integer> inOrder=new ArrayList<Integer>();

//Method
void Inorder(Node curr)
{
    if(curr!=null)
    {
        if(curr.left!=null)
            Inorder(curr.left);
        inOrder.add(curr.data); //Appending to list
        if(curr.right!=null)
            Inorder(curr.right);
    }
}

//Now after method call:
boolean isBST(ArrayList<Integer> inOrder)
{
    for(int i=1;i<=inOrder.size();i++)
        if(inOrder.get(i)<inOrder.get(i-1)) //Not possible in BST
            return false; 
    return true
}
```

2. **How to determine if given tree is a Heap:** Simply satisfy the property that the parent is >= it's children. We can write a simple recursive solution for that like this:

   ```
   boolean isHeap(int[] arr, int i, int n)// array storing the tree, initial postion , size
   {
      if (i > (n - 2)/2) //Root
          return true;

      // If an internal node and is greater than its children, and
      // same is recursively true for the children
      if (arr[i] >= arr[2*i + 1]  &&  arr[i] >= arr[2*i + 2] &&
          isHeap(arr, 2*i + 1, n) && isHeap(arr, 2*i + 2, n))
          return true;

      return false;
   }
   ```

   You can work out all the 4 conditions in your question from the data I have given you above. I hope this helped!

Comment: Please feel free to point out any bugs. I wrote this in a bit of a hurry